# Require CanvasRenderingContext2D as parent object to function

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, html5-canvas, parent

Is there a way of making a function require a CanvasRenderingContext2D object as parent object? I would like to use this to create additional CanvasRenderingContext2D functions, so like

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.__proto__.strokeRoundedRect = ( x, y, width, height, cornerRadius ) => {

    // Code here...

}
```

**Edit:**

If i run `let context = document.getElementById( "canvas" ).getContext( "2d" ); context.strokeRoundedRect( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );`, I am prompted with this error `Uncaught TypeError: context.strokeRoundedRect is not a function`

Obviously the function doesn't exist, so is there any way of implementing this?

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: I edited the post **^^^**

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apologize for jumping to asking a question. I didn't research the problem thoroughly before posting this thread.

**For anyone interested in a solution to this, read this comment.**

I found out that iterating through an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all canvases, required by using `document.getElementsByTagName( "canvas" )`, it is possible to assign your desired functions to the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) of each individual canvas. I am still not sure if there is a better way of doing this, but [here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6yfs25n/8/) and below you will find the raw JavaScript.

```
let xcd = {};

xcd.initialize = ( context ) => {

    context.strokeRoundedRect = ( x, y, width, height, cornerRadius ) => {

        console.log( "strokeRoundedRect:: ", "X: " + x, "Y: " + y, "Width: " + width, "Height: " + height, "Corner radius: " + cornerRadius );

    }

    context.fillRoundedRect = ( x, y, width, height, cornerRadius ) => {

        console.log( "fillRoundedRect:: ", "X: " + x, "Y: " + y, "Width: " + width, "Height: " + height, "Corner radius: " + cornerRadius );

    }

}

// Get HTMLCollection of all canvases
let canvases = document.getElementsByTagName( "canvas" );

for( let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++)

    xcd.initialize( canvases[ i ].getContext( "2d" ) );
```